# Multiple Xcode projects for a single application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an app that is published on the App Store but recently I decided to rebuild the app so I have a second Xcode project that's named the same. Now I am ready to publish the new app on the App Store but I wanted to make sure it won't creat a duplicate application for my users like it does when I run it on my development device.

Besides making sure the bundle identifier is named the same, what other steps do I need to take so that the upgrade process is as seamless as possible for my users?

Comment: As long as the bundle id is the same and the app is signed with the same certificates, I would have thought they would be considered identical.

Comment: Okay that's what I thought. However when I run the app on my iPhone, it leaves both versions on my phone. I guess upgrading via the App Store is different.

Comment: When I start a version I duplicate the whole folder of the current one with classes, project file etc. I edit that and upload a new version. I have done it many times without any problems, so I think that you should be fine. I am also pretty certain that iTunes connect will protest if it thinks that it is different app.

Comment: Feel free to add your answer and I can mark it as accepted. Thanks!